# How to make two iOS apps share plists?

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist, entitlements

I am making an iOS app that has a free version and a paid version. When a user gets the paid version he/she mustn't lose any of the free app's data. The data is stored as plists.

How to I configure the Entitlements file to enable this? And how do I move (import) the plists to the paid app's Documents directory in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to I configure the Entitlements file to enable this?

This has nothing to do with the entitlements.

> And how do I move (import) the plists to the paid app's Documents directory in my code?

You don't - an app cannot possibly access the sandbox of another one. (Well, actually, if you are developing for jailbroken devices, then this is not a problem, but it seems you're targeting the AppStore, right?)

Two things you can do.

1. Make one version of the app and use in-app purchases to give users access to paid features (this is preferred), or
2. [Store data in the keychain](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/04/03/keychain-group-access.html), and set both apps' keychain access group to the same one. This way they can share data. (Now this is something you would actually set in the entitlements property list.)

Comment: Oh that's what I meant - keychain access. Thank you!